# Создание среза (диапазона) дат

Tags: julia

Как в Julia создать нечто вроде `2019-12-01, 2019-12-02 ... 2019-12-31`? В смысле строку из дат месяца.

Answer (score 0):

Вестимо, читая внимательно [документацию](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Dates/).

```
# using Dates

join(collect(Date(2019,12,1):Day(1):Date(2019,12,31)), ", ")
```